# set cmake variable from custom command before every build

Tags: cmake, command

How can I run a custom command before every build and pass the result to a cmake variable?

I know I can do that on the terminal for example
`cmake -DMY_VARIABLE=$(echo FOOBAR)`

But I'd like to integrate that in my CMakeLists.txt using
`add_custom_command(TARGET ${MY_APP} PRE_BUILD ...)`.

Then I want to pass that variable as a compile definition.
`add_cmpile_definitions(MY_DEFINITION="${MY_VARIABLE}")`

I found something similar in the command `execute_process` which has an argument `OUTPUT_VARIABLE` that stores the output of the command into that variable. But I think it doesn't run before every build.

Comment: Note, that changing a CMake variable implies **reconfiguration** of the project: `cmake` needs to be run again and needs to produce the project's Makefile's. That is, if you build your project with `make`, then building the project with changed variable is **effectively** `cmake -DMY_VARIABLE=$(echo FOOBAR) && make`. Is it what do you want actually?

Comment: @Tsyvarev If I understand correctly you're trying to say that I'll have to reconfigure cmake each time. That's not what I want actually... I want to run a command and pass its output to a compile definition each time make runs

Comment: "I want to run a command and pass its output to a compile definition each time make runs" - This is impossible, CMake generates Makefile with hardcoded compiler options. You may, however, wrap a compiler with custom script or program, which adds needed options.

Comment: Perhaps generating a header file containing the definition may be an option...

Comment: @fabian This sounds better I think, I'll give it a try! Thanks!